# Heroku change start script

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm running a node.js service on Heroku, by default Heroku runs `npm start` while starting the deployed service, but I'd like to run some other script from my `package.json`. I have tried adding `Procfile` here's my procfile content.

```
web: npm run start-fastify
```

but Heroku is still running `npm start`, It just works fine when I run `heroku local web`.

I'm attaching screenshots below.

[image]

Profile content
[image]

package.json -> script
[image]

Heroku deployment log
[image]

What am I missing here??

Comment: Is your file actually called `Procfile` or `procfile`? Those are different things, but if you're developing on Windows it will probably let you get away with lower-case.

Comment: I tried both. Still no luck

Comment: btw why are you saying  `if you're developing on Windows it will probably let you get away with lower-case` .. I'm deploying on Heroku.. I Want Heroku to run this script while deploying.not worried about local env.

Comment: Because you said that `heroku local web` works, and _that_ happens on your local machine. Windows filesystems default to case-preserving-but-not-differentiating, which could make `procfile` work with `heroku local`. But it would definitely _not_ work when you deploy. On Heroku, which has a case-sensitive filesystem, you must use `Procfile`.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you've deployed a version to Heroku that contains your `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris I have attached screenshots.

Comment: Those screenshots don't answer my question. _Are you entirely sure that you've deployed a version to Heroku that contains your `Procfile`?_

Comment: I haven't added it to `.gitignore` and I have pushed my latest changes to Heroku. Is there any other way I can find out whether `Procfile` is present in Heroku?